# Gallery grid not aligned correctly until browser resize

Tags: html, css, joomla

http://www.funkylemondesign.info/index.php?option=com_advportfoliopro&view=project&id=4:hitchingbrooke-hospital&catid=95:architectural-models&Itemid=587

The advanced portfolio pro on this page doesnt align correctly until you resize the browser window. Been stuck on this for a while now, any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: Please post some code to help us see and better understand what exactly is happening.  Anyway to post just the gallery snippet?  Also, from my initial inspection, creating an image gallery with a bunch of images nested in divs with absolute positioning isn't the most efficient use of code.  We could accomplish a complete responsive gallery with far less code.

Comment: im afraid it's a module so not a lot has been changed with it https://extstore.com/joomla-extensions/components/advanced-portfolio-pro. If it's any help by setting a height onto the gallery grid div it fixes the problem but then it isnt responsive

Comment: do you need more information?

Comment: Try changing `$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.gallery-grid').masonry({
   itemSelector: '.grid-item'  
  });
 });
` to `$(window).load(function() {
  $('.gallery-grid').masonry({
   itemSelector: '.grid-item'  
  });
 });
`

Comment: It worked, Thank you very much!!